# node js return request response from another/child function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an async method, inside the async method I'm calling another function. So I just want, if another function doesn't exist data, then want to return response from another function.

Please follow the below example:

```
async function generate_lineup(req, res) {
    var email = req.body.email;
    check(email); // it handle global varibale & push data
    
database.insertdata();

}

async function check email(email) {

    // if error or email already exist then return from here
    return res.status(404).json({'status':'failed','message':'email already exist'});
}
```

Comment: You are missing `return` statement here: `check(email);`

Comment: but after adding return, it will not go next line of code

Comment: Point is, you are not accepting output of `check()`. You can use await or return, but that is based on your requirement

Comment: no, i edited my question. check function only need to manage errors & if no error, then push data into global variable & then code will move on next lineof code... also i'm calling this function multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

```js
async function generate_lineup(req, res) {
    var email = req.body.email;
    return await check(email);

}

async function check email(email) {

    // if error or email already exist then return from here
    return res.status(404).json({'status':'failed','message':'email already exist'});
}
```

like this ?

update

```js
async function generate_lineup(req, res) {
  var email = req.body.email;
  const res = await check(email);
  if (res.stausCode === 404) return res;
  database.insertdata();

}

async function check email(email) {

  // if error or email already exist then return from here
  return res.status(404).json({'status':'failed','message':'email already exist'});
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. there can me more line up code after calling chck_Email function, so can't return function.

Comment: there is any possibility to return response from another method ?

Comment: @SoravGarg  I updated my answer, please check if it is useful for you?

Answer (score 0):

Two ways of doing this :
The straight forward one is just passing the res object to the checkEmail function

```
async function generate_lineup(req, res) {
    var email = req.body.email;
    check(email,res);

}

async function checkEmail(email,res) {

    // if error or email already exist then return from here
    return res.status(404).json({'status':'failed','message':'email already exist'});
}
```

The better way of doing this would be avoiding that and handling the response logic inside the "controller" depending on what the checkEmail function returns ( its return value could be changed to an object to fit more scenarios )

Comment: after passing res inside check_email function. getting below error.

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning:   Error: [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT] [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers aft  er they are sent to the client

Comment: The second way pushing the data only in global variable.

Comment: in the first way, getting this error. (node:6218) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning:   TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined
above one is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to do it like this :

```
async function generate_lineup(req, res) {
  var email = req.body.email;
  try {
    await check(email);
    return res.json({'status':'success'});
  } catch(e) {
    return res.status(404).json({'status':'failed','message':e.message});
  }
}

async function check(email) {
// if error or email already exist then return from here
  throw new Error('email already exist');
}
```

Comment: I've to call check_email function need to call multiple times, so I want to return response in check_email function. because i want to reduce no of the line of code, otherwise I'l need to call every time try/catch and then return response.

Comment: I think it's cleaner that way but you can return a status from check function and then return the response from the main function.

Comment: any possibility to return response from the child function ?

Comment: I don't see any clean way to do it.

Comment: try passing `req` object as well. `check(req, res)` in inside check function `req.body.email;` and `res.json({})`;